# Can I remove my close vote when the question is edited?

Tags: support, closing

I was wondering if we could remove our close vote from a question after it is edited and has some added meaning.

I have voted for closing [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6122/2598). Originally, when this question was posted, it was not very constructive and more likely it seems like an open ended discussion question.

But now this question has been edited and seems quite useful to the community. So I want to remove my close vote as already there are 3 close votes and 2 more will result in closing the question. So, is there any way to remove the close vote from a question?

Comment: This is one of the main reasons I tend to not be quick with close votes unless I do not think the question is salvageable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes). However you can go to the Review page (link at the top of the page) and go through the Close queue and vote "Do Not Close"; if a post gets 3 Do Not Close votes it will be removed from the close queue, however others can still vote to close it.

In addition, once the question has 100 views, close votes will start expiring at a rate of one per day unless another close vote is added, at which point the 4-day timer resets. So if you're concerned about it, just check back in a week or so to make sure the votes expired, and if they didn't and the question got closed, just vote to reopen.

Comment: In addition, once the question has 100 views, close votes will start expiring at a rate of one per day unless another close vote is added, at which point the 4-day timer resets. So if you're concerned about it, just check back in a week or so to make sure the votes expired, and if they didn't and the question got closed, just vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2013-07-15, close votes can be retracted.

For more details on that, refer to MSO feature request [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes#comment582472_915)

> **...implemented what [animuson so succinctly suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/167514#167514)**
>
> ...Basically, when clicking the close button again after already having voted to close, change the original "Vote to Close" button to be a "Retract Vote" button:
>
> [image: Retract Vote]
>
> Clicking the "Retract Vote" button will trigger a confirm dialog to confirm that you really want to retract and notifying that the action is irreversible (and you can't vote again). Then once confirmed, simply mark the vote as **expired**...